# php preg_match - pattern for number at end of string, always preceded by space, in turn preceded by any characters?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract a number from a string. The string is a filename,  will be variable in its contents, but will end with a space followed by a number.

So strings like `a b 1212`, `a 1212`. I am not sure if filenames ever end up with a whitespace at the beginning, but something like  `1212` should not produce a match.

I am using so far

```
preg_match('#^(.)* (\d*)$#', $str, $matches);
```

but that returns a match for case of something like  `1212`.

I thought about reversing the string and doing this

```
preg_match('#^(\d*)(\s*)(.*)$#', strrev($str), $matches);
var_dump(strrev($matches[1]));
```

and checking `if $matches[1] != ''` and that seems to work, but I am trying to better understand regex, so that I can do this without the reverse, and figure out proper pattern for the case `get number at end of string, which is always preceded by a space, and where that space in turn is always preceded but anything`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
preg_match("/^\S.* (\b\d+)$/", $str, $matches);
echo end($matches)."\n";
```

For instance if you use the following variable:

```
$str = "1234 lkjsdhf ldjfh  1223";
```

The call to `end($matches)` will return `1223`

Whereas if you use the following variable:

```
$str = " 1212";
```

call to `end($matches)` will remain empty.

Comment: that did it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^\S.*\b(\d+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RajqcM/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\S`: Match a non-whitespace
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any character
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\d+)`: Match any integer number in capture group #1
- `$`: End

Comment: The number at the end can be anything. So things like `a b 1212`, which would return `1212` or something like ` 12-03-23 12:34:43 8888` which would return `8888`.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. It has been updated now

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. That returns the whole match, not the number. The answer above, with `preg_match("/^\S.* (\b\d+)$/", $str, $matches);` seems to be working in all use cases.

Comment: I have provided a regex for validation. It wasn't clear that you wanted a capture group as well otherwise in same regex you can do: `^\S.*\b(\d+)$` to capture it.